# tar filenames with spaces in a one line crontab style tar / find command

Tags: bash, find, cron, tar, ubuntu-16.04

When the following command runs from crontab tar errors occur when a file with spaces in the filename are encountered.

```
/tar -C / -zcvf /root/archive-of-files-with-spaces-in-filename.tar.gz `find /var/www/html -mmin -1450 -print | sed 's|^/||'`
```

Changing the switch to -print0 or removing the -print switch altogether does not solve the problem:

```
/tar -C / -zcvf /root/archive-of-files-with-spaces-in-filename.tar.gz `find /var/www/html -mmin -1450 -print0 | sed 's|^/||'`
```

OR

```
/tar -C / -zcvf /root/archive-of-files-with-spaces-in-filename.tar.gz `find /var/www/html -mmin -1450 | sed 's|^/||'`
```

The same errors are thrown by tar.

How can the command be re-written to allow filenames with spaces to be served to tar without being broken up into directory names that do not exist?

Sample of an error produced with filename: 
"2016-12-15 Name File Repair exportICS.php"

tar: var/www/html-calendar.northpawfamilycloud.xyz/pages/2016-12-15:
      Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Name: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: File: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Repair: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: exportICS.php: Cannot stat: No such file or directory

NOTE | sed 's|^/||'` strips leading slash off finds so tar error "removing leading slash does not occur.

Comment: Why do you have `tar` in the root directory?  It is a weird place to keep an executable.

Comment: in crontab the command line is 1 1 * * * /bin/tar I test at the command line with # tar as /bin is in the PATH environment variable of my server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the only filtering you're doing is to remove leading slashes from names under `/var/www/html`, you can use `tar` alone — avoiding a myriad problems with `find`:

```
tar -C / -czvf /root/archive-of-files-with-spaces-in-filename.tar.gz var/www/html
```

Given a directory, `tar` backs up the contents of the directory.  If you have sub-directories under `/var/html`, your archive was probably twice as big as necessary.  This one won't be bigger than necessary.

---

Apparently, the `find` command includes options.  In that case, you have to do things the other way:

```
(cd /; find var/www/html -type f -mmin -1450 -print0) |
 tar -C / --null -T - --czvf /root/archive-of-files-with-spaces-in-filename.tar.gz
```

The `cd /; find var/html` avoids leading slashes from `find`.  The `-print0` uses null terminators for the file names.  The `--null` tells `tar` to expect file names to be null-terminated; the `-T -` says read the list of file names from standard input.

You can put all that on a single line if you wish.  It isn't the way I'd do it.  I would create a script that would be run by the `cron` (`crontab`) system that would do the job, especially since the output file name would inevitably be time-stamped if I was running it, and it would probably identify which site was being backed up, etc.  The site to be backed up would be a parameter to the script, supplied by the `crontab` entry.  That's my preference; there are plenty of people who write long lines into their `crontab` files.

Also, GNU `tar` (noisily) omits the leading slash from archive names, so that there are never absolute names inside a `tar` file generated by GNU `tar`:

```
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
```

That means you could avoid the sub-shell and simply use `find /var/www/html …` to generate the names, living with the warning message.  Since you have verbose output anyway, that's not likely to be much of a problem.

Comment: I presented the tar command with the find because I typically add switches to the find to enable various incremental backup techniques, such as adding --mmin -1450 to the find statement to only archive files with modify timestamps 24hours 10 minutes old.

Comment: /var/www/html contains one small site / /var/ww/html1 contains the next smal site and so on.

Comment: I came here to find how to prepare a tar with specific files containing spaces, I needed the `--null -T -` parts – as usual, it was faster than studying the man page ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Archive with spaces**:

Escape spaces with backslashes or quote the filename. Example:

```
tar czvf /my/path/filename\ with\ spaces.tgz files...
```

**If the files to be archived have spaces in their names**:

Use `find ... -print0` to separate filenames with NULL `tar ... --null` to only consider NULL terminated files. From [GNU tar documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/nul.html):

```
find /path ... -print0 | tar  ... --null -T -
```

Comment: This is missing the problem.  The problem is not the archive name — it has no spaces in it anyway.  The problem is the handling of entries in `files...` that have spaces in the name.

Comment: This would work to tar one file with spaces, but is no good for a command tar'ing hundreds of files at once.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: yes, you're right. I did edit my answer.